# uwp background task has no effect in release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

I created a background task for my UWP project.But I tried many times and found the background task works fine in DEBUG mode every time but has no effect in RELEASE mode.I checked background task and I'm sure that the codes and settings of background task have no problem.
I'm curious about it.Actually,I have faced this problem last year so I think it may not be problem of Visual Studio.Did anyone face a same question?

---

update in August:I checked it many times these days,and found the problem maybe came from my uwp project.I tried the background task codes in two different uwp projects and found it run well in one project but didn't run in another,but the codes involving with background task in these two projects is same(I copied it from one project to another project.)That' so strange!I will continue checking the code.

---

update: OK,I still didn't really solve this problem...I tried many times,copied codes from one project to another new project,but only one project's background task works well..I will continue trying....

Comment: For this question, we need to do troubleshooting. You said `you're sure that the codes and settings of background task have no problem.` Since I have not saw your complete code, I'm not sure. Please use the official [BackgroundTask](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask) sample to test in release mode. If it works, then your code may have some issues. If not, please tell me the OS build version, the target/min version of your UWP project and the background task `Windows Runtime Component`.

Comment: Thank you.I will give detailed description and codes of the problem after I trying your suggestion.

Comment: Have you solved your question?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have been dealing with other things for the last month. So I didn't reply to you last month.I just tried the official sample. I found the official sample also didn't work under RELEASE mode. I have updated my question.